# How can I change the year to 2023 as I move on to next year's January in my calendar website?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm creating a Calendar Website where I have displayed "July 2022" as current month/year, but unfortunately, as I click my next or previous buttons to change to the next month/year the year seems to be stuck at 2022 but the month changes accordingly. Any ideas on how to fix this? I would highly appreciate the help!
Below is my HTML and JS code:

```html
            <div class="month">
                <div class="previous">
                    <span>&#10094</span>
                </div>
                <div class="full-date">
                    <h2 id="month"></h2>
                    <h3 id="year"></h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="next">
                    <span>&#10095</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
"use strict";

const date = new Date();
let year = date.getFullYear();

const render = () => {
    date.setDate(1);

    const monthDays = document.querySelector(".date");
    const lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    const previousLastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
    const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();
    const lastDayIndex = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDay();
    const nextDays = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;
    
    const months = [
    
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
    ];

    document.querySelector(".full-date h2").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];
    document.querySelector(".full-date h3").innerHTML = year;
    document.querySelector(".full-date p").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();
    
    let days = "";
    
    for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--) {
        days += `<div class="previous-date">${previousLastDay - x + 1}</div>`
    }
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++){
        if (i === new Date().getDate() && date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) {
            days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
        } else {
            days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
        }
    }
    
    for (let g = 1; g <= nextDays; g++) {
        days += `<div class="next-date">${g}</div>`;
    }
    monthDays.innerHTML = days;    
};

document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener("click", () => {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    render();
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    render();
});

render();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies where you're defining the year.
If you put it in the render function after you setDate, it will work.

```js
const render = () => {
    date.setDate(1);
let year = date.getFullYear();
//....
}
```